# how to empty json file before dumping data into it

Tags: python, json

**python 3.5**

hi i have following codes to add an element to json data :

```
jsonFile = open("json.json", mode="r+", encoding='utf-8')
jdata = json.load(jsonFile)
jdata['chat_text'].insert(0, {'x':'x'})
json.dump(jdata, jsonFile)
jsonFile.close()
```

but it would be result:

**first data**

```
{"chat_text": [{"a": "b", "c": "d", "e": "f"}]}
```

**edited data**

```
{"chat_text": [{"a": "b", "c": "d", "e": "f"}]}{"chat_text": [{'x':'x'},{"a": "b", "c": "d", "e": "f"}]}
```

so i wrote this code :

```
jsonFile = open("json.json", mode="r+", encoding='utf-8')
jdata = json.load(jsonFile)
jdata['chat_text'].insert(0, {'x':'x'})
open('json.json', mode='w').close() #deleting first data
json.dump(jdata, jsonFile)
jsonFile.close()
```

result would be this :

**first data**

```
{"chat_text": [{"a": "b", "c": "d", "e": "f"}]}
```

**edited data**

```
                                               {"chat_text": [{"x","x"},{"a": "b", "c": "d", "e": "f"}]}
```

as you can see it replaces first data with space and i want it to be nothing...

any ideas?

Comment: why do you load before and after updating json, simply load json into file after updating `char_text`

Comment: There is a syntax error in your **edited data** json. It is not valid json

Comment: why do you load before and after updating json, simply load json into file after updating `char_text`

Comment: open('r') -> load -> close --> open('w') -> dump -> close.

Comment: `jsonFile.seek(0); json.dump(jdata, jsonFile)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is essentially that you are opening the file twice in different modes.

```
jsonFile = open("json.json", mode="r")
jdata = json.load(jsonFile)
jsonFile.close()
jdata['chat_text'].insert(0, {'x':'x'})
jsonFile = open('json.json', mode='w+')
json.dump(jdata, jsonFile)
jsonFile.close()
```

So the first 3 lines open your file and load it into jdata, then close that file.
Do whatever manipulation you need
Open the file again, for writing this time. Dump data, close file.